# Trying to compare a string to a string found inside an object that is inside an array using contains()

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift

I have a string (newName) that I would like to see if it already exist in an array(namesArray) of objects (Players). Each object in the array has a string property(name), and that is the property I would like to compare to the newName string.

I tried to do something like this

```
if namesArray.contains(newName) {
  //do something
}
```

but I know this will not work because it's comparing the object itself and not the string inside of the object, I'm just not sure how to dive one level deeper to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the closure form of contains:

```
if contains(players, { $0.name == newName }) {
    ...
}
```

Which is an abbreviated form of:

```
if contains(players, { (item) -> Bool in return item.name == newName }) {
    println("contained")
}
```

Comment: is the $0 a representation of the array increasing index levels on each loop through?

Comment: In a closure with unnamed parameters (no `(...) -> ... in` part), $0 is the first argument to the closure.

Comment: I would suggest getting and reading the [Apple Swift book](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11), it's available from iTunes for free and contains a lot of information on things like closures, syntax, methodology, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'm slowly switching from obj-C to swift, so I may be off the mark, but try this:

```
for name in namesArray {
  if name == newName {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: This assumes that namesArray is an array of names, what the question asks is an array of objects with a name property.  The preferred form of your response would be just `if contains(players, newName)`  No need to write iterators yourself, save the block levels :)